# Cannot remove top and bottom padding from button with custom background

Tags: android

**rounded_button_blue.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/buttonBlue" />
    <corners
        android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

**fragment.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sunbedButton"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_blue"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:text="@string/sunbed_button"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I have a button with a custom background. Here's how it looks:

[image]

I want to decrease the amount of padding above and under the text. As you can see, I've set `android:padding="0dp"`, but the top and bottom padding is still there. It does work to force the padding away by doing `android:layout_height="small_value"` but obviously that is not a good solution.

Is there any way to remove the top and bottom padding of the button?

Comment: There is no padding. It's the default Button with width 115dp. You could set it to `wrap_content`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been clearer. It is the padding on the top and bottom that I don't want. Setting width to `wrap_content` doesn't remove that padding, only the horisontal padding. Clarified in the question.

Comment: Still it's 0dp padding. Try to set the height to xxdp if you want it less

Comment: As I've stated in the question, I know that this is a possibility, but I'd rather find out why "padding" is added automatically.

Comment: There is no extra padding!!! This is the default look of **no** padding

Comment: It might not be called padding but there is certainly some extra pixels above and under the button. I'd like to know why and if there's another way to change it without setting the height explicitly.

Comment: Maybe you see it as padding because you set a small textsize

Answer (score 0):

try this once

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@color/buttonBlue" />
      <corners android:radius="20dp" />
      <padding
      android:bottom="0dp"
      android:left="10dp"
      android:right="10dp"
      ndroid:top="0dp" />
 </shape>
```